# Button click in each row in a dynamically created table to retrieve a column value of the corresponding row

Tags: javascript, html

//Button click  in each row in a dynamically created table to retrieve a column value of the corresponding row

```
var rowCount = result.rows.length;// to count numrows coming from database
for(var j=1; j<=rowCount; j++)
{
var row = result.rows.item(j-1); // creating rowindex in the table
exercise =row.Exercise; // value from database 
time= row.Time; // value from database 
userid = row.UserId // value from database

var table = document.getElementById("check"); // table id 
var row1 = table.insertRow(j); // Insert Row To Table 

 var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");
 element1.type = "text";
 element1.value = exercise;
 cell1.appendChild(element1);

 var cell2 = row1.insertCell(1);
 var element2 = document.createElement("input");
 element2.type = "text";
 element2.value = time;
 cell2.appendChild(element2);

 var cell3= row1.insertCell(2);
 var element3 = document.createElement("input");
 element3.type = "button";
 element3.value = "edit";

var cell4= row1.insertCell(3);
```

var element4= document.createElement("input");

```
element4.value = userid;
cell4.appendChild(element4);
cell4.style.dispalay="none";

element3.addEventListener('click', function () { 
alert('event fired!'); 
// get the userid value of the clicked  button as an alert 
});
}
```

Comment: make your question more clear. Also loop closing parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all assign each of the elements a unique id. For example:

```
var cell4= row1.insertCell(3);
var element4= document.createElement("input");
element4.type = "text";
element4.value = userId; // from DB
element4.id = "element4-" + j;
cell4.appendChild(element4);
```

Assign your `edit` button id = j.

```
var cell3= row1.insertCell(2);
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.type = "button";
element3.value = "edit";
element3.id = j;
cell3.appendChild(element3);
```

Then assign onclick handler to your edit button inside the for loop like this:

```
element3.onclick=doSomething;
```

Create a function `doSomething()`

```
function doSomething() {  
   for(var j=1; j<=rowCount; j++)
   {    
       var value = document.getElementById("element" + j + "-" + this.id).value;
       alert(value);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Hashim and Jose For Your Answers, @Hashim : The Value Of Only the first 2 fields appears , i need the value of the last field which is hidden , and i have not understood   element4.id = "element4-" + j;
 how it works ... .can you explain as well as  var value = document.getElementById("element" + j + "-" + this.id).value; ... I am newbee in javascript, wil be greatful

Comment: In the above case if there is 1 row only 1 column value will be repeated that is the first column , i want the code in such a way where if there are 3 columns and 1 row all the coulumn value needs to be alerted , would you also tell me how to hide one of the fields in the above code ... coz  cell4.style.dispalay="none";
doesnt seem to work

Comment: Actually cell4.style.dispalay="none" works i have to give it after the end of dynamically created table and it works

Comment: I would also like to store each of the cell values in separate variables .

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some row id and class to the columns then you can use

```
jQuery(".your_class").click(function(){
var column_value = jQuery(this).html();
});
```

did you mean something like this ?

Comment: Am still writing my code , but something is wrong with editing in stack overflow .

Comment: ok does anybody know how i can pass the  corresponding column values when the edit button of a particular row is clicked